# Spring <mvc:resources /> returns 404 error

Tags: spring-mvc

I can't get `mvc:resources` to work, it returns HTTP 404 error. Relevant part of my applicationContext.xml:

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/app_images/" />
```

I have a .jpeg file in the folder C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/app_images called "user_dfd3f052138649fe8e76fb46e62e2417.jpeg". If I go to the address http://localhost:8084/Pro/resources/user_dfd3f052138649fe8e76fb46e62e2417.jpeg I get a http 404 error, but I can get this image with the url file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/app_images/user_dfd3f052138649fe8e76fb46e62e2417.jpeg

Potentially relevant part of my deployment descriptor file:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>imagesFolderRoot</param-name>
    <!--<param-value>/home/asus/app_images/pro</param-value>-->
    <param-value>C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\app_images</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>allowedUploadImageExtensions</param-name>
    <param-value>image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: why not put the file on application's classpath i.e put it in a sub-folder within the resources folder rather than trying to retrieve it from your hard-drive?

Comment: I really cannot understand that moment - do not I lose all the uploaded images if I redeploy the project or remove the tomcat, etc ? Can you please explain what is the best place to keep my uploaded files for permanent storage? I stored files in oracle/mysql/mongodb or via ftp://, but not directly in the resources folder :)